# Unexpected Behavior With Basic Gaussian Elimination in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, gaussian

I am trying to solve a system of linear equations in matrix form using one of the many widely-available routines, specifically this function `gauss` (along with sample data with a known result), but regardless of which elimination strategy I use I consistently get incorrect results and don't know where to turn at this point.  My code:

```
    MODULE gaussMod
    CONTAINS
    function gauss(a,b) result(x)
        implicit none
        real*8 :: b(:), a(size(b), size(b))
        real*8 :: x(size(b))

        real*8 :: r(size(b))
        integer i,j, neq

        neq = size(b)

        do i =1, neq
            r = a(:,i)/a(i,i)

            do j = i+1, neq
                a(j,:) = a(j,:) - r(j)*a(i,:)
                b(j) = b(j) - r(j)*b(j)
            enddo
        enddo

        do i= neq, 1, -1
            x(i) = (b(i) - sum(a(i, i+1:) * x(i+1:))) / a(i,i)
        enddo
    END function
END MODULE

SUBROUTINE outFile(n,x)
    IMPLICIT none
    INTEGER n
    INTEGER i
    REAL*8, DIMENSION(n) :: x


    OPEN(UNIT=20,FILE="solution.csv",action="write",status="replace")

    DO i=1, n
        WRITE (20,"(1(f0.30,',',:))") x(i)
    END DO
    CLOSE(20)
END SUBROUTINE

PROGRAM elimtest
        USE gaussMod
        IMPLICIT none
        INTEGER, PARAMETER :: coeff_kind = selected_real_kind(p=30, r=99)
        INTEGER n
        REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: a
        REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: b
        REAL*8, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: x
        n = 4

        ALLOCATE(a(n,n))
        ALLOCATE(b(n))
        ALLOCATE(x(n))

            a(1,1) = 18.
            a(1,2) = -6.
            a(1,3) = -6.
            a(1,4) = 0.
            a(2,1) = -6.
            a(2,2) = 12.
            a(2,3) = 0.
            a(2,4) = -6.
            a(3,1) = -6.
            a(3,2) = 0.
            a(3,3) = 12.
            a(3,4) = -6.
            a(4,1) = 0.
            a(4,2) = -6.
            a(4,3) = -6.
            a(4,4) = 18.

            b(1) = 60.
            b(2) = 0.
            b(3) = 20.
            b(4) = 0.


        x = gauss(a,b)
        CALL outFile(n,x)


END PROGRAM
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *I consistently get incorrect results* isn't much help in diagnosing the problems here.  Be much more explicit, the ways in which a program's outputs differ from what is expected are a very useful tool in figuring out problems.  And, while I'm writing, it probably wouldn't do any harm to specify the `intent` of each argument to each routine.

Comment: Explain how are the results unexpected and inconsistent. Show them!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the following line

```
b(j) = b(j) - r(j)*b(j)
```

is a typo of

```
b(j) = b(j) - r(j)*b(i)
```

With this modification your code gives the correct result (probably!):

```
x(:) = 8.3333333333333339  6.6666666666666670  8.3333333333333339  5.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Because "i" and "j" look rather similar in the terminal, I usually avoid using "j" as an index, although a matter of taste... For the same reason, I avoid using "l" (el) as a single letter. This practice helps pretty much in my case.